# [UITableView transform in x direction but in this direction table rows moving in all directions.]

Tags: objective-c

I used transform property for UITableView but after completing this transform process tableview rows moving in all direction .Please solve this problem.

`CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-1.5707963);
scrollingTable.transform = transform;
   scrollingTable.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];`

Answer (score 0):

If you talking about UITableview Orientation then you can implement following code in your viewcontroller class for orientation of viewcontroller work in only Landscape Left and Right.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) ;
}
```

If not so please explain your problem with something code or image.